# Record count from LIMIT query

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

We are using a LIMIT/OFFSET query with the FMDB library.  I know that I can easily get a count from the FMResultSet, but because we only return a subset of the records it will not be the count of the available records.  Does anyone know if there is a DB variable I can call that will give the total count from the previous query?  Trying to avoid issuing a full count query due to performance concerns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way to get the count is to not use `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`. This is true with raw SQLite. It's not a limitation of FMDB.

Comment: `Trying to avoid issuing a full count query due to performance concerns.` How else do you expect to count the number of rows? Most DBs won't bother fetching rows past the `OFFSET+LIMIT`, because there's no reason to, so the "full count" won't be available.

Comment: Thank you, I agree also.  I thought there might be some internal stat I could grab, was thinking like the primary key value type of thing.